# how to get icmp on udp socket on UNIX

Tags: c, unix, udp, ping, icmp

Getting raw sockets requires root privilege, and tcp/udp doesn't have it,
so I need to know how to get a udp socket and fetch icmp data.
The programming language is C and the OS is BSD-like.

(In other words I want to write a ping without root privilege)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is an OSI layer four protocoll, so is ICMP. Thereby, you can't implement ICMP on an UDP socket since its layer four protocoll is already fixed to UDP. You can consider writing an implementation that requires the privilege to open a raw socket. Then you either give the application or your account the right capability or flip the executables SUID bit to make it run as root.

Comment: Do you know that ICMP messages are essential to the transport layer aswel ? each UDP and TCP sockets (i'm talking BSD/POSIX sockets) get handed a copy of ICMP messages.

Comment: @jean-loup Can you show me a piece of documentation that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: The internal communications are usually not documented. You can either try my solution below, read an OS book, read a networking book, read the kernel code, or deduce it by reading udp/tcp/ip man pages (e.g.: the SO_BSDCOMPAT option).

Comment: @jean-loup That's completely wrong. You can have full-feature TCP/UDP server working perfectly fine without ICMP implemented. And ICMP doesn't even have ports, you can't link an ICMP message to a socket. Imagine the mess if every socket on a system received every (totally unrelated) ICMP message.

Comment: @ElderBug I'm not talking about the possibility of having a server working without ICMP, I'm talking about POSIX sockets. And POSIX sockets considers ICMP messages as control messages. Also, the ports ARE present in ICMP messages (in the payload, see RFC1812).

Comment: @ElderBug and you would have big trouble with timeouts if you don't handle ICMP *-unreachable in TCP. I'm not sure why you would want to run a server without ICMP neither.

Comment: @jean-loup I'm not going to argue about that, it's getting subjective. It's true that you can actually match some ICMP message to a socket, but TCP/IP layers never rely on ICMP, because ICMP is defined as optional by the standard, and is not "essential" as you said.

Comment: @ElderBug I don't know which standard you are referring to (RFC791 ?), but IP without ICMP is not viable with UDP/TCP POSIX sockets. Maybe the early TCP/IP standards did not rely on ICMP but those that POSIX sockets are based on certainly does. Once again, I'm talking about POSIX sockets, not about sending UDP/TCP segments without implementing ICMP, which is irrelevant nowadays.

Comment: @ElderBug Also, RFC792 is pretty old and states that implementing ICMP in every IP module is mandatory (MUST).

Comment: @jean-loup I was talking about RFC1812. Most messages are defined as "should be sent", and routers "may have an option to not send messages".  Anyway, OSes nowadays do NOT rely on ICMP, mostly because it isn't secure. Legitimate error messages are sent by random IP from intermediary routers, and afaik, there is no way to authenticate an ICMP message. Imagine if a client close a connection when receiving an ICMP. You don't even have to spoof IP, its too costly to check if the IP is really an intermediary.

Comment: @jean-loup And most (=all) NAT won't bother translating ICMP payload, thus making it impossible to match sockets in most case. Just check yourself, you won't find any OS that timeout a TCP connection when receiving ICMP unreachable.

Comment: @ElderBug I can assure you that a lot of NATs are actually translating ICMP payloads, you can check yours with this tool: http://www.tracebox.org/

Comment: @ElderBug Also, we are talking about different things. You're talking about the standards, I'm talking about the POSIX implementation and I can affirm that they (the sockets) get handed ICMP messages.

Answer (score 3):

**You can write an UDP ping without root privileges.**

> When the **IP_RECVERR** option is enabled, all errors are stored in the
>   socket error queue, and can be received by **recvmsg**(2) with the
>   **MSG_ERRQUEUE** flag set.

[See the UDP manual.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)

I assume the forge&send routine is already implemented on a SOCK_DGRAM socket.
Then, to access the source addresses of the ICMP messages:

- Set the socket options to receive errors (IP_RECVERR)
- Make a call to recvmsg() on the error queue (MSG_ERRQUEUE)
- Parse the returned structures (msghdr and iovec), it contains the source addresses of ICMP issuers.

Answer (score -2):

So, uh, it it was trivial to go around the requirement, do you think it would still be there?

It's meant to provide some security, so it's not super-easy to go around.

I don't think it can be done.